# Update query using join errors as multipart identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please point out to me where I am doing wrong here? I am trying to update the temp table by joining the `ABCD` table by a condition(`@USEAB` variable). In some of our customer databases, the `ABCD` table doesn't exist hence the variable returns Y or N.

```
DECLARE
@USEAB NVARCHAR(2) = 'N'

DECLARE @TEMPTABLE TABLE (REGID NVARCHAR(8), REF NVARCHAR(6), ITEM INT, PRD NVARCHAR(6), SOURCE NVARCHAR(2), TRANID NVARCHAR(10))

IF @USEAB = 'Y' BEGIN
    --OBTAINING CASH TYPE THROUGH TRANID
    UPDATE @TEMPTABLE
    SET TEMP.REGID = AB.REGID, TEMP.REF = CASE WHEN AB.PRD IS NULL THEN 'INVOICE' ELSE  'CASH' END, TEMP.PRD = AB.PRD
    FROM @TEMPTABLE TEMP
    INNER JOIN ABCD AB
    ON AB.TRANID = TEMP.TRANID
    WHERE TEMP.SOURCE =  N'AB'
    AND TEMP.TRANID IS NOT NULL
END
```

I got 'The multi-part identifier TEMP.REGID could not be bound'.

Comment: If I try to run  the above, I get no errors. If I change `@USEAB` to `'Y'` I (obviously) get an error that the table `ABCD` doesn't exist, as we lack DDL for it. Though your statement makes little sense, you define `@TEMPTABLE` with the columns `REGID`, `REF`, `ITEM` and `PRD`, but in the `UPDATE`  try to refercene the columns `SOURCE` and `TRANID`; those don't exist in that table variable.

Comment: Hi I have updated the question to include the columns into the temp table.

Comment: We still need a [mre], @Sri .

Comment: You said no errors ? I ran the same and got the  'The multi-part identifier TEMP.REGID could not be bound'. Is this something to do with the Intellisense ?

Comment: Correct, I get no errors. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8d12828799c58364c4c5bc37e1732e6d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave your @TEMPTABLE the alias `TEMP`. You may not refer to it with its original name anymore. Change

`Update @TEMPTABLE`

to

`Update TEMP`

Comment: Thanks a lot, George. Now all the errors from the Temp table are gone but the AB errors `Invalid column name REGID`

Comment: Well, does ABCD have an REGID column?

Comment: ABCD table doesn't exist in the database hence the IF condition. My expectation is to skip this block if the variable @USEAB = 'N'. But when I execute this I get the error even though the variable returns 'N'

Comment: That isn't how SQL Server, @Sri . It compiles the code, so if you have references to invalid columns like that it can't generate a plan because the code can't be compiled. It's like having an `If` in C#, but within your `If` you reference a text box that doesn't exist; you'll get a compilation error when you try to build the application.

Comment: It is as Larnu says. One way to conditionally bypass a table is to use dynamic sql.

Comment: ah cool. Understood now. I will modify by using the dynamic sql. Thanks @larnu